# object of type 'LambdaContext' has no len()

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-redshift

I am trying to deploy python function into AWS lambda

Below is my code sample.

```
import psycopg2

from password.redshift_credentials import username, password, host, port, database



def security_group_update(event,context):
    # connect to Redshift, psycopg2 library used for running SQL statements
    con = psycopg2.connect(dbname=database, host=host, port=port, user=username, password=password)
    

    for i in range(len(context)):
        print(context)
        command = "GRANT USAGE on schema " + context[i] + " TO GROUP " + event + ";\n " + \
                  "GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA " + context[i] + " TO GROUP " + event + ';'
        print(command)
        # Opening a cursor and run copy query
        cur = con.cursor()
        cur.execute(command)
        con.commit()

    # Close the cursor and the connection
    cur.close()
    con.close()
    return {
        "statusCode": 200
    }

group = 'analytics'
schemas = ['acquisition',
           'cohort_analytics',
           'dev_vegalash_traffic_sources',
           'facebook28',
           'facebook28_veg2'
           ]
security_group_update(group, schemas)
```

I am getting this error ...

Response
{
"errorMessage": "object of type 'LambdaContext' has no len()",
"errorType": "TypeError",
"stackTrace": [
"  File "/var/task/security-group-permissions.py", line 12, in security_group_update\n    for i in range(len(context)):\n"
]
}

Wonder if anybody faced the same issue.

Comment: Well, a context has no length, why you expect it to have one? Iterating through the context does make no sense at all. Iterating through something within `event` does maybe make sense.

Comment: @luk2302 How can I found this code, I mean we have group and schemas and if I am iterating values by events then what should be correct format? Sorry I am new to lambda so I have no idea.

Comment: Just print the event and try to understands its contents

Comment: @luk2302 Please Review the below answer, I am still getting error. Test Event Name
event

Response
{
  "errorMessage": "0",
  "errorType": "KeyError",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 12, in lambda_handler\n    command = \"GRANT USAGE on schema \" + event[i] + \" TO GROUP \" + 'analytics' + \";\\n \" + \\\n"
  ]
}

Answer (score 0):

```
import psycopg2
from password.redshift_credentials import username, password, host, port, database


def lambda_handler(event, context=None):
    # connect to Redshift, psycopg2 library used for running SQL statements
    con = psycopg2.connect(dbname=database, host=host, port=port, user=username, password=password)
    
    schema= event["key"]
    for i in range(len(schema)):
        command = "GRANT USAGE on schema " + schema[i] + " TO GROUP " + 'analytics' + ";\n " + \
                  "GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA " + schema[i] + " TO GROUP " + 'analytics' + ';'
        print(command)
        # Opening a cursor and run copy query
        cur = con.cursor()
        cur.execute(command)
        con.commit()

    # Close the cursor and the connection
    cur.close()
    con.close()
    return {
        'statusCode': 200
    }
```

We should need to define event["key"] to any variable name.
And if you key value it's in the form of list then your event format should look like this.

```
{
   "key":["acquisition","cohort_analytics","dev_vegalash_traffic_sources"]
}
```

Thank you Luke, the event thing works.